# Powershell Remoting: Load local script inside script

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I launch a local script on a remote computer with:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer -FilePath C:\myFolder\Script1.ps1
```

This script dot-sources another script (*Script2*), which also is located on my local computer in "C:\myFolder". This fails because *Script1* trys to load the *Script2* from the remote computer.

Is there a way to load *Script2* from my local computer inside *Script1* inside the remoting session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Workaround]

1. Create a session to the remote server
2. Use the session to load the script2
3. use the same session to run the script1.

eg:- `$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server`

`Invoke-command -Session $Session -FilePath <script2>`  this should load functions

`Invoke-command -Session $Session -FilePath <script1>`

here the functions in `script2` will be available for `script1` to consume, so no need to refer and dot source `script2` .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can work the way you outlined it since code running on the remote machine cannot find a file that is relative to the local machine.

The only way to achieve this is to share your script and include it as with a UNC path, or an administrative share, like `\\localmachine\c$\users\test\script\a.ps1`.
But there's a chance you'll run into authentication issues (double hop).

The (easiest) solution: copy all your scripts to the remote machine first and make sure that the paths used in the scripts will work.

Comment: Isnt there any way in general where you can adress a local path of the source machine inside remoting session? I thought I read something like that some time ago. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Do you think of: [implicit remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720181.aspx)? that allows you to use comandlets that are only available on a remote computer.